# Thymeleaf/Spring MVC - How do you nest variables/expressions in a Link expression?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, template-engine, thymeleaf

For example, my controller method in Spring does this:

```
model.addAttribute("view_name", "foobar")
```

And I'm trying to do this in my Thymeleaf template:

```
<link th:href="@{/resources/libs/css/${view_name}.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But the rendered result is this:

```
<link href="/app/resources/libs/css/${view_name}.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

So it's not replacing the `${view_name}` like I'm expecting.

What am I doing wrong? In general, how do you nest expressions like that in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since you are not starting the url rewrite with an expression (e.g. `${...}`, `#{...}`, `|...|`, `__...__`, `'quoted string'`, ...), Thymeleaf will consider the whole expression as a `String` and not execute any of the inner expressions.

The following example would work because it starts with an expression.

```
@{${attribute}}
```

For your example you have the following possibilities

**Literal substition** (preferred method)

You can do literal substitions in a `String` with the pipeline syntax (`|`).

```
<link th:href="@{|/resources/libs/css/${view_name}.css|}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**String concatenation**

```
<link th:href="@{'/resources/libs/css/' + ${view_name} + '.css'}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is Literal substition the preferred method?

Comment: Do you know how to unescape custom attributes? I'm trying to do `th:attr="ng-include=@{/resources/html/report-tab-divs/mainreport.html}"` which outputs `ng-include="/hp-dsat/resources/html/report-tab-divs/supported-data-report.html"`, but I really want it to output `ng-include="'/hp-dsat/resources/html/report-tab-divs/supported-data-report.html'"` (notice the extra single quotes). How would I make ThymeLeaf give me that full context path wrapped in single quotes inside double quotes?

Comment: I tried setting `th:inline="none"` on a parent element then doing `ng-include="'[[@{/resources/html/report-tab-divs/mainreport.html}]]'"` but that won't work either; ThymeLeaf leaves it alone.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't able to find the literal substitution anywhere but it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @trusktr did you try with `'''...'''`? (triple single quote)