# Concatenated themyleaf expression does not render data in URL

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
<tr th:each="user : ${team.getMembers()}">
   <td th:text="${user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}"><a href="#">Name</a></td>
   <td th:text="${user.initialName}" class="initial-name"><a href="#">Employee Initials</a></td>
   <td th:text="${user.positionTitle}" >Position In Team</td>
   <td th:text="${user.currentStatus}">Current Status</td>
   <td>
      <center><a th:href="@{sip:${user.initialName}@test.com}" class="hvr-pulse-grow" style="cursor: pointer;">
         <i class="fa fa-skype fa-2x" style="color: #00aff0;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </center>
   </td>
</tr>
```

The interesting bit:

```
<a th:href="@{sip:${user.initialName}@test.com}"><i class="fa fa-skype fa-2x" style="color: #00aff0;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

I'm expecting the URL when rendered to look like this:

```
sip:ABCD@test.com
```

But I get:

```
sip:${user.initialName}@test.com
```

Basically, the variable is not rendered in the anchor, but it does show up above, for example at `<td th:text="${user.initialName}" class="initial-name"><a href="#">Employee Initials</a></td>`, i.e. it shows the expected `ABCD` value in the table data cell.

So what's going wrong here?

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059314/thymeleaf-spring-mvc-how-do-you-nest-variables-expressions-in-a-link-expressio#answer-22064656) which i think is applicable to your issue aswell...

Comment: Thanks! This ended up working: <a th:href="@{'sip:' + ${user.initialName} + '@test.com'}">